# Why $ not work in split method?

Tags: java, string

I have following code to split a string:

```
String s = "100$ali$Rezaie" ;
String[] ar = s.split("$") ;
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because [`public String[] split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts **Regex** as an argument and not a String.

`$` is a [meta-character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) that has a special meaning.

You should escape this `$`: `\\$`.

By escaping this, you're telling `split` to treat `$` as the **String** `$` and not the **Regex** `$`.
Note that escaping a String is done by `\`, but in Java `\` is wrote as `\\`.

Alternative solution is to use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) that "*Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String*:

`String[] ar = s.split(Pattern.quote("$"))`

Answer (score 6):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex as an argument. `$` is a meta-character used as an anchor to match end of a `String`. The character should be escaped to split on a literal `$` `String`

```
String[] ar = s.split("\\$");
```

Answer (score 5):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex as an argument.

> `public String[] split(String regex)`
>
> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

You need to escape the `$` sign.

```
String[] ar = s.split("\\$")
```

You need to say `\\` because the `\` needs to be escaped too!

Comment: @MarounMaroun I might have been older but SO wouldn't permit :)